# Bash Script Loop Issues (SSH into VMs)

Tags: bash, shell, virtual-machine

I have a bunch of VMs that i want to setup with a Bash Script. I got a Text file with all IP Addresses of all the VMs and also have written "ssh VM-Name" infront of each line so when my script is reading each line, it will SSH into each VM and then execute my commands inside that VM. It somehow breaks the loop and stops after SSHing into the first VM. How do i exit the first VM so that it can SSH into the next one?

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

cat nodes.txt|while read sshlink
do
    echo -------------------------------------------------------
    echo Creating Users on: $sshlink
    $sshlink 'echo connecting...; sleep 2; echo Creating...; sleep 1; sudo apt     
    install ntp; uname -a; sleep 1; sleep 2; echo disconnecting...; exit;'
done
```

Content of nodes.txt

```
ssh node1@IP
ssh node2@IP
ssh node3@IP
ssh node4@IP
```

It does SSH into the first VM, it will execute the commands i specified but it will not exit and loop into the next and so on.

```
MyUsername$ ./setupnodes.sh 
-------------------------------------------------------
Creating Users on: ssh node1@TheIPAdressofthatVM
connecting...
Creating...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
ntp is already the newest version (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Linux node-1 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017      
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
disconnecting...
```

Comment: You can write an expect script to do this simpler https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288099/how-to-write-expect-in-shell

Comment: you could use `ssh -v ...` to print more logs to dig deeper.

Comment: `disconnecting...
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3940, received 3908 bytes, in 6.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 611.1, received 606.1
debug1: Exit status 0
+ exit `

Comment: Try to run the $sshlink with parameters with the eval command. It may solve problems when command is in variable. Other option, if nothing helps,  try to use scp to copy a script to remote hosts, and ssh to run the script

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. I have used it for similar issues:

```
while read -r remote_host;
do
   ssh $remote_host bash -s <<"END"
   echo "Do Something"
   echo "Do something else"
   ...
   echo "Closing connection"
END
done<$1
```

The script will accept a list of hosts delimited with new lines, ssh to each one perform the action. Each command can be put on a new line.

This script uses heredoc notation.